# Why does Unity crash every other time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keras

I want to integrate Keras.NET (https://scisharp.github.io/Keras.NET/index.html) in my Unity application to import a previously-trained model in python and use it into my app.
Since Keras.NET is a NuGet package and cannot be installed in Unity, I followed this tutorial (https://jonfoust.medium.com/using-gcp-nuget-packages-with-unity-8dbd29c42cc4) and added the .dll files to a "Plugins" directory into my Assets folder. I also added a "link.xml" in the root folder of my app to reference the .dll files.

With that, I can use Keras, import and use my model to make predictions in Unity BUT I can't start my application twice in a row because Unity crashes the second time. I have to restart Unity completely :/

So the question is, Why my app crashes every second time I want to launch it ?

Comment: Sounds a bit like maybe some resources like e.g. FileStreams in some background threads are not cleaned up correctly when you quit the application? -> Next time the resource is still locked -> your new instance can't access them